# why the implicit convertion can be complied

Tags: c++

define some class such as:

```
class Data{
  public:
    Data() = default;
    Data(Data const&){
     std::cout<<"invoked"<<std::endl;
    }
};

class DataA: public Data{

};

class DataB {
public:
  DataB() = default;
  DataB(DataA const&){}
};
```

example 1:

```
class Test{
  public:
    Test() = default;
    Test(void*){}
};
int* ptr = nullptr;
Test t = ptr ;  //complie ok
 /*
  void* tmp = ptr;  //implicit convertion once
  Test t = Test(tmp); //implicit convertion twice
 */
```

example 2:

```
class Test{
  public:
    Test() = default;
    Test(Data){
     std::cout<<"a"<<std::endl;
    }
};
 DataA a;
 Test t2 = a;  //complie ok
 /*
  Data tmp = a; //implicit convertion once
  Test t2 = Test(tmp); //implicit convertion twice
 */
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

example 3:

```
class Test{
  public:
    Test() = default;
    Test(DataB){}
};
 DataA b;
 Test t3 = b; //complie error
 /*
  DataB tmp = b; //implicit convertion once
  Test t2 = Test(tmp); //implicit convertion twice
 */
```

example 3 error
g++:
[image] 
clang:
[image]

Above, these code ,All of them are implicited convertion twice

Question 1:
The c++ standard said the expression can only implicit convertion once,why the example 1 and example 2 are both compiled successfully

Question 2:
Relative to example 1 and example 2,why the example 3 is complied error,they all implicit convertion  twice

Comment: There's nothing that tracks how often data is typecast. I think you've misunderstood something from the standard.

Comment: Remember that inheritance is an ***is-a*** relationship. An instance of the `DataA` class *is-a* `Data` instance as well. There's really no conversion from a `DataA` object to a `Data` object, only *slicing*. Also remember that the *is-a* relationship of inheritance only goes *one way*. `DataB` is a `DataA` is a `Data`, but `Data` is *not* `DataA`, and `DataA` is *not* `DataB`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is-a is that reference or point to Data,but Data is a object ,the complier should generate temporary object from DataA to Data,so Data(Data const&) should be invoke

Comment: References or pointers doesn't matter here: The is-a relationship works anyway. References and pointers are only needed if you want *polymorphism*.

Comment: By the way, when asking questions involving build errors, please include the full and complete copy-pasted output of the build. Depending on the error it could be helpful to point to a specific part of the error message to help you understand what's going on.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If you set the Data(Data const&) = delete, you shouldn't convert a DataA object to Data object,the Data(Data const&)  can be invoked ,If you need Data from DataA,So Data tmp = a (DataA object),The complier invoked the Data(Data const&) member function

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Updated the code  and add some image

Answer (score 6):

> The c++ standard said the expression can only implicit convertion once

It does not.  You are allowed an unlimited standard conversions.  What you are limited on is user defined conversions.  You are only allowed one user defined conversion in a conversion sequence.  That means that

```
Test t = Test(tmp);
```

has zero implicit conversions as `Test(tmp)` is an explicit conversion and the copy is eldied so it is the same as `Test t(tmp);`.  This is also the same thing that happens for `Test t2 = Test(tmp);` in your second block.

In

```
Test t2 = a
```

`a` is a `DataA`, but a `DataA` is a `Data` since it is derived from `Data` so there is an implcit conversion to `Data`.  That means you only have one user defined conversion going from `Data` to `Test` so it is allowed.

The problem with

```
Test t3 = b
```

is that `b` is a `DataA`, but `Test` takes a `DataB`.  That means you need to convert `b` to a `DataB` which is a user defined conversion and then you would need to convert that `DataB` into a `Test` which would be a second user defined conversion.  That is why you get an error.  If you did

```
Test t3 = DataB(b);
```

then it would compile as there would only be one implicit user defined conversion (you can have as many explicit ones as you want).

Comment: The "tmp" is what I imagine the complier are,not the real code.Though,DataA extends from  Data,but In my understand,The complier will invoke Data(Data const&) function when user write the code "Data a = DataA{}",so this is user defined conversition,and Test t3 = a,It 's the second user defined conversition

Comment: @jackX When doing `Data a = DataA{}` it will call `Data(Data const&)` as it needs to actually construct an object.  In `Test t2 = a` though it doesn't need to do that.  You can call `Test(Data){}` directly with anything that derives from `Data` since it is a `Data`.  This is called object slicing and is an implicit conversion, not a user defined one.

Comment: Thanks,but what I'm confused is, Test(Data) ,If you set the argument of DataA,the imagine code is the complier will generate a temporary Data object,the code like Data tmp = argument ;It will call Data(Data const&),this function is user defined,What you said means the complier will considered the convertion from DataA to Data which is not a user defined convertion?

Comment: @jackX Exactly.  When you call `Test(Data)` with a `DataA`, it doesn't call `Data(Data const&)`.  What happens instead is the `Data` part of `DataA` gets sliced off implicitly and no user defined conversion is used.

Comment: but,when you define the Data(Data const&){std::cout<<"invoked"<<std::endl;},Test t2 = a,It will print something,How to explain this?

Comment: @jackX What compiler are you using?  It does not get called [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/164158d00b6cc4e6)

Comment: vs,gcc,clang all print "invoked" and the website what you gived also print the "invoked"

Comment: @jackX Oops.  Your right, it is called, not sure how I missed that.  This is because `Test(Data)` takes by value so it makes a copy when it calls `Test(Data)`.  It is not invoking `Data(Data const&)`  first in order to call `Test(Data)`.  If you used `Test(Data const&)` you would see no copy is called.

Comment: Yes,I see,the refrence is not invoked copy construcor,but Data needs,So the complier should invoke Data(Data const&) what is user defined firstly,and the convertion result as tmp,So Test t2 = tmp,the second user defined convertion will invoke,twice,why the code can be complied?

Answer (score 1):

Example 1 converts `int*` to `void*` and then passes the `void*` to the ctor of the class (explicitly).

Example 2 incurs **slicing**. This compiles but it is most likely not what you want, given that you copy a Base from a Derived.h

Finally, Example 3 attempts to chain two user-defined conversions. As you point out, C++ does not allow that. You can invoke the A to B conversion explicitly and then you can pass it implicitly to Test.

Comment: @NathanOliver Absolutely missed that, thanks. Will edit.

Comment: @NathanOliver Your answer is much more thorough than mine and should be accepted. I'll leave mine here as a tldr.

Comment: Though,DataA extends from Data,but In my understand,The complier will invoke Data(Data const&) function when user write the code "Data a = DataA{}",so this is user defined conversition because user defined the Data(Data const&) function ,and Test t3 = a,It 's the second user defined conversition,what's wrong with my understand?

Comment: But you are copying an object x as though it was a `Data` but in reality it is `DataA`. That means that you treating x as a type that it is not. Derived types can do whatever they want and do not have to fulfil any contracts regarding internal consistency from their parent types. Slicing leads to generally bad things.

Comment: @bitmask You said means when Slice DataA to Data,the convertion what complier  considered is not be a user defined convertion?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code

```
DataA a;

Test t3 = a;
```

is that that there is required the default copy constructor `Test( const Test & )` that is it is a copy-initialization.

The initializer shall have the type `Test`. To get an object of the type Test there are required two user-defined conversions

```
DataB(DataA const&){}
```

and

```
Test(DataB){}
```

The Standard does not allow to apply two user defined conversions.

From the C++ Standard (15.3 Conversions)

> 4 **At most one user-defined conversion** (constructor or conversion
>   function) is implicitly applied to a single value

If you will rewrite the code the following way

```
DataA a;

Test t3( a );
```

then there is used the direct-initialization and there is required only one user-defined cobversion

```
DataB(DataA const&){}
```

and the code will compile.

As for other code snippets then let's consider this example

```
int* ptr = nullptr;
Test t = ptr ;
```

In this example there is used an implicit conversion from the type `int *` to the type `void *` and the user-defined conversion from the type `void *` to the type `Test`. That is there is used only one user-defined conversion.

As for the example 2 then an object of a derived class is at the same time is an object of its base class. There is no used a user-defined conversion except from the type `Data` to the type `Test`.

Pay attention to that this class

```
class Test{
  public:
    Test() = default;
    Test(Data){
     std::cout<<"a"<<std::endl;
    }
};
```

is ill-formed. According to the C++ Standard (15.8.1 Copy/move constructors)

> 5 **A declaration of a constructor for a class X is ill-formed if its
>   first parameter is of type (optionally cv-qualified) X** and either
>   there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have
>   default arguments.

Comment: Thanks ,I already understand the example 1 and example 3,but example 2,DataA to Data,also invoke the user defined actor Data(Data const&),and Data to Test is second user defined converstion,why the code right?

Comment: @jackX In the example 2 an object of a derived class is also an object of its base class. There is no conversions except from Data to Test..

Comment: When change the define  Data(Data const&){} to  Data(Data const&){std::cout<<"invoked"<<std::endl;} ,Test t = a in exmple 2,"invoke" will print,How to explain this,here the user defined convertion is called

Comment: @jackX It is invoked due to this constructor Test(Data){} because the argument is passed to the constructor Test by using the copy constructor of the class Data. If you will change the constructor the following way Test( const Data &){} then a new object of the class Data will not be created and you will not see the message. In any case it is not a user-defined conversion.

Comment: What you means is ,though passed by value,Data(Data const&) invoked,but the complier considered the convertion from deveride to base is not a user defined convertion even if Data(Data const&) what user defined  invoked?

Comment: @jackX For starters see my appended post. You have a constructor Test(Data){ So a copy of an object of the type Data is created using the expression "a". So the copy constructor of the class Data is used to create the temporary object used as an argument of the constructor Test(Data). But using the copy constructor of the class Data does not mean using a conversion.

Comment: ,the key is because DataA is derived from Data,so from DataA to   Data even if call copy constructor Data(Data const&),It's not a convertion,hence ,also it's not a user defined convertion?